# Button and AJAX not responding

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im working on trying to get a button to run a php script with AJAX. To be clear I am really new to javaScript and PHP so my code might be completely wrong. I think that the problem is in my button click code not so much the ajax code. Any help is great

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".submit").click(function myCall() {
        var subdata = $("#form").serializeArray();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "construct_new.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: subdata
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    <div>   
        <form id="form">
            Name of Product: <input type="text" name="productName" value="Enter Here">
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? What doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: there's no php here, so if there's a possible problem in there, you should include that code in your question, and "how" this is used and hopefully not as `file:///`.

Comment: so if this isn't a php question, the tag needs to be removed; it's misleading.

Comment: *"Button and AJAX **not responding**"* - That's ironic; neither are you. Did you leave the question? Or just not bothering?

Comment: @AlexHowansky *lol* ^ so, you still waiting also? I'm about to take out that php tag in about a minute.

Comment: I removed the php tag. If there's relevance, you'll need to add it back in after.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Heh nope, closed the window a while ago.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I followed your lead. One gives them attention to hopefully solve their issues with code that isn't there, *right*. Well, I'll be off.... *again*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [DOM ready wrapper](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) around the jQuery because it executes before the element exists (or is rendered by the browser).

You can use either `$(function(){ })` or `$(document).ready(function(){ });`.

```
$(function(){
    $(".submit").click(function myCall() {
         var subdata = $("#form").serializeArray();
         var request = $.ajax({
             url: "construct_new.php",
             type: "GET",
             data: subdata
         });
         return false;
     });
});
```

In this case, you don't need `serializeArray()` but simply `serialize()`.

There is no success or complete function defined and so you wouldn't see anything when submitting this, unless of course you watch the developer console/net tab.

Also, using a form's submit event is preferred to the submit button's click event.

```
$(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function myCall() {
         var subdata = $(this).serialize();
         var request = $.ajax({
             url: "construct_new.php",
             type: "GET",
             data: subdata,
             success : function(response){
                 console.log("success!");
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: That got the button working thanks! Im getting a different error now, I am going to troubleshoot it now and come back if I get stumped again. Once again Thanks!

Comment: If my PHP file is creating and using session variables would session_start() need to be in both the original page and the php script, or only in the script?

Comment: session_start() needs to be in any PHP that needs to read or write to the session.

Answer (score 0):

Put your jQuery inside a document ready like this, and prevent the default action (to submit the form):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var subdata = $("#form").serializeArray();
                $.get("construct_new.php",{data: subdata}, function(){
                     console.log(data); // whatever returned by php
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Document ready makes sure page has finished loading everything. e.preventDefault() stops the default action (for a form, submission, for an a tag, following the link).